# Ruby MySQL formatter

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby

I need to 'pretty print' a mysql query.  The query is very long and complex and doing this in code is cumbersome.  The language doesn't matter too much, but I am writing a web app so javascript ( to do it client side ) or ruby ( server side ) would be ideal.

Are there any libraries out there that will do this for me?

I imagine it would do something like this...

```
   s = "select foo, bar from baz join bif on baz.id = bif.id where bar = 10"

   f= format( s ) # this would return something like the following.

   f = "SELECT
         foo,
         bar
       FROM baz
       JOIN bif
       ON baz.id = bif.id
       WHERE bar = 10"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using the sqlformat web service that appspot offers.  I could have written my own web service using the above Sql Beautify method, but I did not want to introduce a new language into our code repository ( we only use ruby, python, and javascript ).

```
# Hits the following web-service
# http://sqlformat.appspot.com/format/

# Github page
# https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/

# Documentation
# http://sqlformat.appspot.com/api/
# data - The SQL statement to format.
# remove_comments - Set to 1 to remove comments.
# keyword_case - How to convert keywords. Allowed values are 'lower', 'upper', 'capitalize'.
# identifier_case - How to convert identifiers. Allowed values are 'lower', 'upper', 'capitalize'.
#  - while this is an option I found it capitalizes table names which breaks the query. BE CAREFUL
# n_indents - An integer indicating the indendation depth.
# right_margin - An integer indicating the maximum line length.
# output_format - Transfer the statement into another programming language. Allowed values are 'python', 'php'

# {
#   :data => query,
#   :format => 'text',
#   :remove_comments => 1,
#   :keyword_case => 'upper',
#   :n_indents => 2,
# }

# or, just pass in a the query as a string and the above params will be the default

def DB::format_sql( params )
    if( params.class == String )
        params = {
            :data => params,
            :format => 'text',
            :remove_comments => 1,
            :keyword_case => 'upper',
            :n_indents => 2,
        }
    end

    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://sqlformat.appspot.com/format/'), params )
    return res.body
end
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are indeed language agnostic then the Perl module [`SQL::Beautify`](http://search.cpan.org/~jkramer/SQL-Beautify-0.04/lib/SQL/Beautify.pm) will pretty print your above sample query.

once installed (by issuing for example `cpan SQL::Beautify`) you could format your query string using a oneliner similar to this:

```
echo "select foo, bar from baz join bif on baz.id = bif.id where bar = 10" |\
perl -ne 'use SQL::Beautify; print SQL::Beautify->new(query => $_)->beautify;'
```

which will yield this:

```
select
    foo,
    bar
from
    baz
    join bif on baz.id = bif.id
where
    bar = 10
```